# Unable to build a swift project through Xcode on my iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

About 10 months ago I created a simple game and just stopped working on it but at the time I was able to build and run it on my iPhone. Now I came back to it and I can build and run it fine using the Simulator but when I connect my iPhone to my laptop and try to build & run on my device the build fails.

I also have a developer license associated with my Apple ID

Phone on iOS 12.1.4

Xcode on version 10.1

The error I get when the build fails is as follows:[Screenshot of messages located right above the error code pasted below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucMDU.png)

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission\ Objective.app (in target: Mission Objective)
cd /Users/user/Documents/Mission\ Objective
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk
builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 9638951FC180A2C69D96322E2A5AB695F1F00070 --scan-executable /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission\ Objective.app/Mission\ Objective --scan-folder /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission\ Objective.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission\ Objective.app/PlugIns --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission\ Objective.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission\ Objective.app --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Mission\ Objective.build/Debug-iphoneos/Mission\ Objective.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: 6
libswiftCoreAudio.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
libswiftGameplayKit.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftGameplayKit.dylib
libswiftModelIO.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftModelIO.dylib
libswiftAVFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
libswiftUIKit.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
libswiftSceneKit.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib
libswiftDispatch.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
libswiftMetal.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
libswiftGLKit.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftGLKit.dylib
libswiftSpriteKit.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftSpriteKit.dylib
libswiftDarwin.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
libswiftos.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
libswiftCoreImage.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
libswiftCore.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
libswiftObjectiveC.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
libswiftCoreMedia.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib
libswiftsimd.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib
libswiftFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
libswiftQuartzCore.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is up to date at /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Codesigning /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 9638951FC180A2C69D96322E2A5AB695F1F00070 --verbose /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

error: Failed with exit code 1
```

This is pretty overwhelming and I'm not sure how to diagnose this issue. I'd be thankful if someone has seen this before or could point me in the right direction. I'll be happy to provide any other information you might need to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it fails to sign your code.

```
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mission_Objective-hiufpyxwvsqqucfybrbffprxvtju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mission Objective.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib: code object is not signed at all
```

Check that you have set a Team in your project settings under Signing.

Comment: https://imgur.com/4EO0qLl            Is this what you mean? If so, then yes. I set it under myself

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to clean before building ?

product->clean
product->build